# Remove chapter numbers from figure captions in a \chapter*

Tags: captions, chapters

I want "Figure 1" but I get "Figure 0.1":

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\DeclareSIUnit\parsec{pc}
\DeclareSIUnit\lightyear{ly}

\title{Astropedia}
\subtitle{space, explained}
\author{Matt Undis}
\date{March 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Astronomy}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Crab Nebula}
\centering
\includegraphics{220px-Crab_Nebula}
\end{figure}
```

Replace `220px-Crab_Nebula` with any image you want. How do I remove the "0." from "Figure 0.1"?

Comment: Should the figure numbers be reset at each chapter or be independent?

Comment: @Bernard They should be independent (continuous).

Comment: In this case, just add to your preamble `
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}`.

Comment: @B Didn't know it was that easy, thanks.

Comment: @Bernard, add it as an answer so the question doesn't stay answerless.

Answer (score 4):

To have a continuous numbering of the figures in a document, without the chapter number in front of the figure number, just re-define in the preamble the command used to display the figure numbers:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```